# Chef template processed before service is created

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I have a problem with running chef 12 in AWS OpsWorks.

Basically one of my Deploy Recipes during deploy creates an NGINX-App.conf for each Application deployed. This one works fine.

However i want to have this template created and ran Only if NGINX was installed on server, incase i have an instance without putting webserver/nginx there.

My run_list would like this:

1. Nginx package, nginx service enabled, started.
2. During deploy Nginx-app specific conf file is created.

My recipe for creating Nginx-app conf looks like this:

```
  template 'nginx.conf' do
    path "/etc/nginx/conf.d/#{params[:something]}.conf"
    source 'nginxapp.conf.erb'
    cookbook 'nginx'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 0644
    notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]'
    only_if { File.exists?('/usr/sbin/nginx') }
  end
```

It fails if i add "only_if" condition because it seems like Nginx is not installed before this template gets processed.

If i run this second time it will work properly because nginx will be already installed.

Anybody knows what can be wrong here?

Regards,
Andres

Answer (score 0):

So apparently i made it work like this:

1. Moved "template" part to original "nginx" cook as a Definition and left only_if part there.
2. Inside Deploy cookbook/recipe i just call this custom definition from "nginx" cookbook that creates template.

This way file exists and condition works properly, i have no idea why...

Is it something to do with using template from other cookbook gets executed before everything else?

Comment: It has nothing to do with in which cookbook it is, more to being moved into a definition. I've the feeling your run_list is not in the order your think it is as it should have worked.

Comment: Aight thanks! Then it might seem like an AWS OpsWorks bug with their new chef environment.. Although it's strange. If my Deploy cookbook would run whole before Nginx setup, all other commands would fail as well.

Comment: In this case maybe OPSworks chef version has a different behavior on guards, sounds unlikely. side note: Try with `{ ::File.exists?` (prepend with two colon to get root File class) to be sure to use Ruby class and not Chef's one , I think there were problems with that but can't remember exactly where.